# B2B graphql - company query displays null for company user id

Tags: graphql, user, magento2-b2b, company

I am working on Graphql API (Magento - 2.4/ enterprise edition) for B2B, the default company query which lists the company users does not give the id since it is deprecated.

But I want to update a company user as a logged-in company admin from the Client for which I need the user id.

I tried using users attribute and structure attribute in the query but was unable to get the id for any company user. Could anyone help me with this ??

[update company user](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/update-company-user.html)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6CXU.png) : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/company.html
[3][image]

Answer (score 0):

As in the document you attached, this API doesn't have data of "userid". If you need to get this data then you need to customize this API.

Or you can use email to get the desired data.

From the email field, you need to call the customer table to get the customer with the current email and from here you can get the user's ID.